# Sub query regresa mas de un valor, como solucionarlo sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL Server y cuando me regresa mas de 1 dato el subquery me manda este error, como puedo solventarlo?

intente agregarle un in como vi en algunas soluciones pero no me funciono o no pude aplicarlo bien

```
SQL error has occurred on query Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. OpenSQLExceptionCategories: []
```

Consulta sql

```
SELECT [TBAPLICACIONES].[FCAPLICACIONID]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FCNOMBRE] AS FCNOMBREAPP
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FCURL]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FITIPOAPLICACIONID]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FITIPOUSUARIOID]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FIESTATUSID]
      ,(SELECT TBUSUARIOS.FCUSUARIO 
        FROM [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].TBUSUARIOS
        LEFT JOIN  [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO
        ON TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FCUSUARIO = TBUSUARIOS.FCUSUARIO 
        AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FCAPLICACIONID =  [TBAPLICACIONES].[FCAPLICACIONID]
        WHERE TBUSUARIOS.FINUMEROEMPLEADO = '[Param.1]' AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.[FCAPLICACIONID] = [TBAPLICACIONES].[FCAPLICACIONID]
        AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FIESTATUSID != 3)
        AS FCUSUARIO
      ,(SELECT TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FCPERFILID 
        FROM [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO
        WHERE TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FCUSUARIO = (SELECT TBUSUARIOS.FCUSUARIO 
        FROM [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].TBUSUARIOS
        LEFT JOIN  [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO
        ON TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FCUSUARIO = TBUSUARIOS.FCUSUARIO 
        AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FCAPLICACIONID =  [TBAPLICACIONES].[FCAPLICACIONID]
        WHERE TBUSUARIOS.FINUMEROEMPLEADO = '[Param.1]' AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.[FCAPLICACIONID] = [TBAPLICACIONES].[FCAPLICACIONID]
        AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FIESTATUSID != 3)
        AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.[FCAPLICACIONID] = [TBAPLICACIONES].[FCAPLICACIONID] AND TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO.FIESTATUSID != 3)
        AS FCPERFILID
  FROM [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].[TBAPLICACIONES]
    group by [TBAPLICACIONES].[FCAPLICACIONID]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FCNOMBRE]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FCURL]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FITIPOAPLICACIONID]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FITIPOUSUARIOID]
      ,[TBAPLICACIONES].[FIESTATUSID]
```

Comment: aplica un filto de limitar a un resultado la sub query que te genera el error

Comment: @John no. no se debe hacer eso...

Comment: Si un subquery te esta devolviendo mas de un valor, entonces debes analizar cual de ellos es, y porque motivo. un subquery, debe devolver solo una fila.. que fila queres??? te sirve cualquiera? si esta devolviendo mas de una, todas tienen el mismo valor? revisa tus subquerys, fijate que valores traen, y fijate que valor realmente queres traer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de solucionar el problema de que las subconsultas retornan más de un valor, lo mejor es simplificar la consulta para no usar subconsultas.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT /*Para quitar la clausula GROUP BY si no hay funciones de agregado*/
       A.[FCAPLICACIONID]
      ,A.[FCNOMBRE] AS FCNOMBREAPP
      ,A.[FCURL]
      ,A.[FITIPOAPLICACIONID]
      ,A.[FITIPOUSUARIOID]
      ,A.[FIESTATUSID]
      ,PAU.FCUSUARIO
      ,PAU.FCPERFILID
  FROM [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].[TBAPLICACIONES] AS A
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT  U.FCUSUARIO
                    ,P.FCPERFILID
                    ,P.FCAPLICACIONID
                FROM  [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].TBUSUARIOS U
                JOIN  [BDTK].[SQCONFIGURACION].TBPERFILESXAPPXUSUARIO P ON P.FCUSUARIO = U.FCUSUARIO 
                WHERE U.FINUMEROEMPLEADO = '[Param.1]' 
                AND   P.FIESTATUSID != 3) PAU ON A.[FCAPLICACIONID] = PAU.[FCAPLICACIONID];
```

Comment: Gracias, eso resolvió mi problema, no sabia que es mejor no usar subconsultas

Comment: Las subconsultas no son malas, pero cuando son repetitivas resultan costosas.